# Why is vi (but not cat) showing ^[[31m[^[[m^[[31m" after I use sed and output to a file I then edit?

Tags: sed, vim, regular-expression, vi, escape-characters

When I use

```
cat Variables/user-extensions.js | sed -e 's/css/XXX/'
```

on an input file of the form

```
storedVars["css_body"] = "css=body";
storedVars["css_main"] = "css=main";
```

I see output such as

```
storedVars["XXX_body"] = "css=body";
storedVars["XXX_main"] = "css=main";
```

However if I add `> x` and then use vi to edit the `x` file I see

```
storedVars^[[31m[^[[m^[[31m"XXX_body"^[[m^[[31m]^[[m ^[[31m=^[[m ^[[31m"css=body"^[[m^[[31m;^[[m
storedVars^[[31m[^[[m^[[31m"XXX_main"^[[m^[[31m]^[[m ^[[31m=^[[m ^[[31m"css=main"^[[m^[[31m;^[[m
```

instead of

```
storedVars["XXX_body"] = "css=body";
storedVars["XXX_main"] = "css=main";
```

which *is* what I get if I let the output go to standard output, or if I only `cat` the output file and don't edit it with vi.  I can `cat` the file and pipe to `head` or `tail` and the output is normal, no extra characters.

If I vi the source .js file I do not see these extra characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in using my aliased cat which adds the special characters.

Instead of

```
cat Variables/user-extensions.js | sed -e 's/css/XXX/' > x
```

use

```
sed 's/css/XXX/' Variables/user-extensions.js > x
```

Comment: If this was really added by `cat`, you should replace your cat with a standard compliant cat.

Comment: No, `cat` does not add the special characters. You've probably aliased or otherwise shadowed `cat` to something that does. Don't do that.

Comment: Yes, my cat is aliased. thx.  Something others might innocently do I think